# problem when running the python application in /etc/rc.local in console mode

Tags: python

I'm coding an application to run when starting raspberry, however when trying to run this error is returned:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

My application is done in *python* with *qt interface*, when I put only `print("test")` the application runs.
How do I correct this?
The **raspberry** is configured in **console mode**

Comment: How do you intend to run a graphical application in console mode?

Comment: You can't start GUI programs from cron or from /etc/rc.local Those both run too early.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/).  We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use QT utility libraries but not the GUI library, you must selectively import only the library components that you need to use. By importing the root `PyQT` package you are setting up the draw thread of the QT system, which requires a display connection.

Comment: I'm importing like this:
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtGui, QtWidget

I'm trying to display an application with Qt graphical interface, display a window with raspberry in console mode.

Comment: I will refer to my original comment, how do you intend to display a window in console mode ? How would this work ? All of the QtGui and QtWidget requir a display connection and a logged in graphical user

Comment: How can I run my application by turning on raspberry without the user seeing the desktop?